# Diagonal Output of a file

Tags: text-processing

How would you output the diagonal of a file?

e.g I got a file with the following inside.

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,0
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,0
1,2,3,4,5
```

The output would be supposed to look like: `1 7 3 9 5` or something like that.

I can output a column via cut (cut -d "," -f5 filename), but I am unsure what to write in order to output the diagonal only.

Comment: In this case (no. of lines = no. of columns) you could use `awk -F, '{print $NR}'`

Comment: @don_crissti I just made the same thought and test. Perfect solution.

Comment: Maybe 17*3*95, or what kind of diagonal do you mean?

Comment: @JeffSchaller The output would simply print out the numbers on the diagonal of the matrix / file, which in this case are 1, 7, 3, 9 and 5.

Comment: The diagonal output should be expected as `1 7 3(not 4) 9 5`

Comment: gentlemen, looks like we have another answer )

Comment: I updated the expected output, based on my understanding of the problem and the sample input; please revert it if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

awk solution, not as elegant as @don_chrissti solution, but works where not a square.

```
awk -F, '{a=a$++n" "}END{print a}' file
```

Comment: The adds an extra space after the last number and before the newline

Comment: One character shorter: `$NR`

Comment: `NF >= NR { print $NR }`

Comment: Prints empty values if there are more rows than columns.

Answer (score 5):

#### Python and numpy

The input data that we're looking at can be treated as a matrix or 2-dimensional array. Now, if we approach the problem from this point of view, there's several computational tools that can be used for manipulating matrices. In particular, Python's `numpy` module allows that. Thus, we could use two things - the `loadtxt()` function and `diagonal()` to extract the desired data:

```
$ python -c 'import sys,numpy;a=numpy.loadtxt(sys.argv[1],dtype=int,delimiter=",");print( a.diagonal() )'  input.txt                                                                    
[1 7 3 9 5]
```

Now, this is the big chunk of the job done. To make the output pretty, we just need to convert the obtained data to strings, and create a space-separated string out of individual ones. Like so:

```
$ python -c 'import sys,numpy;a=numpy.loadtxt(sys.argv[1],delimiter=",");print(" ".join( [ str(int(i)) for i in a.diagonal() ]))'  input.txt                                            
1 7 3 9 5
```

Of course, all this doesn't have to be done as one-liner. For the sake of readability we can make a small script, which will also allow us to process all filenames given as arguments on command-line:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import numpy as np

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    data=np.loadtxt(filename,delimiter=",")
    diag = data.diagonal()
    result_string = " ".join( [ str(int(i)) for i in diag ] ) 
    print(result_string)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. *POSIX* shell:

   ```
   n=0
   while IFS=',' && read x ; do
       set -- $x ; shift $n ; echo "$1" ; n=$((n+1))
   done < inputfile
   ```
2. `bash` can be more concise:

   ```
    n=0; while IFS=',' read -a x ; do echo "${x[((n++))]}" ; done < inputfile
   ```

---

Note that it's easy to get diagonals for all four rotations of the data by filtering to `tac` and `rev`, (or `tac` alone -- **if** the data is a square *.csv* array).  *POSIX* shell examples, but first make some new asymmetric input values:

```
seq 25 | paste -d, - - - - - | tee asym_input
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25
```

1. A `\` *left to right diagonal*, (the *OP* question, with different input):

   ```
   n=0
   while IFS=',' && read x ; do
        set -- $x ; shift $n ; echo "$1" ; n=$((n+1))
   done < asym_input
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   1
   7
   13
   19
   25
   ```
2. A `/` *left to right diagonal*:

   ```
   n=0
   tac asym_input | while IFS=',' && read x ; do
        set -- $x ; shift $n ; echo "$1" ; n=$((n+1))
   done
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   21
   17
   13
   9
   5
   ```
3. A `/` *right to left diagonal*:

   ```
   n=0
   rev asym_input | while IFS=',' && read x ; do
        set -- $x ; shift $n ; echo "$1" ; n=$((n+1))
   done | rev
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   5
   9
   13
   17
   21
   ```
4. A `\` *right to left diagonal*:

   ```
   n=0
   tac asym_input | rev | while IFS=',' && read x ; do
        set -- $x ; shift $n ; echo "$1" ; n=$((n+1))
   done | rev
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   25
   19
   13
   7
   1
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -ne '
   y/,/\n/;G;s/\n$//

   y/\n_/_\n/;:loop
      /_$/{
         s///
         s/^[^_]*_//
         bloop
      }
   y/\n_/_\n/;P

   s/.*//;H
' input.file | paste -sd' '
```

We maintain a ledger on the comma-separated fields to skip in the pattern space in the hold space.

The looping chops the pattern space from both ends to arrive at the situation when the leftmost is ripe for print. We can imagine it to be burning a candle from both ends (however, the rate of burning is different). From  the front we chop a comma-separated field whilst from the end, we drop a trailing `\n`. The burning goes on until there are no more trailing newlines.

And now the diagonal element is sitting at the front of the pattern space.

The artifact `y/\n_/_\n/` is to work around the fact that `POSIX sed` does not have the newline negated inside of a character class, `[^\n]`.

As a last step for the current line, the hold area is incremented. The `paste` command is to get the output in a single line.

---

Provided all fields are numeric in your csv, you could also use the following snippet of `dc`. The `tr` is to remove the commas as dc fields are space delimited and negative numbers begin with _ rather than -

```
tr ',-' ' _' < file | dc -e '[q]sq [s0zlk<a]sa [?z0=qzlk1+dsk<an32ancz0=?]s? 0skl?x[]p'
```

We define 3 macros , `q` for quitting when done, `a` for a looping to delete the elements from the end (popping), and `?` to set up a loop for performing a line-oriented read and invoking the macro `a`, then printing the diagnol element now exposed.

```
tr ... |
dc -e '
   # quit macro
   [q]sq

   # macro to pop elements from stack till they are more than counter k
   [s0 zlk<a]sa

   # do-while loop for reading lines
   [
      ?z0=q       # quit if line read is empty
      zlk1+dsk<a  # increment the counter k and compare it against NF (z) call a if >
      n 32an      # print the diagonal element and a space (no newlines)
      c z0=?      # invoke myself again 
   ]s?

   # main
   0sk  # initialize the counter k
   l?x  # call the macro ? to start the file read-in loop
   []p  # print a trailing newline
'
```

Output:

```
1 7 3 9 5
```

Answer (score 2):

## Abstract:

1. Square.....: `awk -F, '{printf(NR==1?$NR:" "$NR)}END{printf("\n")}' file`
2. Rectangular:

   ```
   awk -F, ' NR==1{printf($1);next}
             {printf(" "$(NR>NF?NF:NR))}END{printf("\n")}
           ' file`
   ```
3. Other diagonals:

   ```
   awk -F, -vdiag=9 -vdir=-1 '
       {d=(NR-1)*(dir>0?1:-1)+1+diag;d=(d<1?1:d);d=(d>NF?NF:d)}
       {printf("%s%s",NR==1?"":" ",$d)}
       END {printf("\n")}
    ' file
   ```
4. Posix that selects diagonal number and direction `/` vs `\`.
   (the code is long, please read it at the end of this post).

---

## Details

#### Square matrix

With awk, the most elegant solution is:

```
$  awk -F, '{print $NR}' file
1
7
3
9
5
```

To have a one line output, you could do (with a trailing space):

```
$ awk -F, -v ORS=" " '{print $NR}' file; echo
1 7 3 9 5
```

If you must have the output without trailing spaces:

```
$  awk -F, '{printf(NR==1?$NR:" "$NR)}END{printf("\n")}' file
1 7 3 9 5
```

#### Rectangular

For a file with, for example, this:

```
$ cat file
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,0
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,0
1,2,3,4,5
a,b,c,d,e
f,g,h,i,j
k,l,m,n,o
p,q,r,s,t
u,v,w,x,y
```

The above solution will print white spaces:

```
$ awk -F, '{printf(NR==1?$NR:" "$NR)}END{printf("|\n")}' file
1 7 3 9 5     |
```

If what you want in this case is to stop processing, then, checking if the  record number is bigger than the number of fields might be a solution (if the number of fields change for each line, this might not be the correct solution):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>NF{exit}{printf(NR==1?$NR:" "$NR)}END{printf("|\n")}' infile
1 7 3 9 5|
```

If what you want is to print the last field in any line where NR > NF:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{printf($1);next}{printf(" "$(NR>NF?NF:NR))}END{printf("|\n")}' file
1 7 3 9 5 e j o t y|
```

#### Other diagonals

If what is needed is a different diagonal than the "main diagonal", we can signal that by setting the variable diag to a value different than 0 (0 is the main diagonal in this code):

```
$ awk -F, -vdiag=3   '   {d=NR+diag;d=(d<1?1:d);d=(d>NF?NF:d)}
                         {printf("%s%s",NR==1?"":" ",$d)}
                         END {printf("\n")}
                     ' file
4 0 5 0 5 e j o t y
```

Note that the value of diag could be negative:

```
 $ awk -F, -vdiag=-3 '   {d=NR+diag;d=(d<1?1:d);d=(d>NF?NF:d)}
                         {printf("%s%s",NR==1?"":" ",$d)}
                         END {printf("\n")}
                     ' infile
 1 6 1 6 2 c i o t y
```

And the diagonal could be like `/` instead of `\` with more math:

```
$ awk -F, -vdiag=4 -vdir=-1 '
    {d=(NR-1)*(dir>0?1:-1)+1+diag;d=(d<1?1:d);d=(d>NF?NF:d)}
    {printf("%s%s",NR==1?"":" ",$d)}
    END {printf("\n")}
' file
5 9 3 7 1 a f k p u

$ awk -F, -vdiag=9 -vdir=-1 '
    {d=(NR-1)*(dir>0?1:-1)+1+diag;d=(d<1?1:d);d=(d>NF?NF:d)}
    {printf("%s%s",NR==1?"":" ",$d)}
    END {printf("\n")}
' infile
5 0 5 0 5 e i m q u
```

#### *Posix* shell

With a different input file:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..6}{1..5} 7{1..3} | pr -ta -5 -s',' | tee inputfile
11,12,13,14,15
21,22,23,24,25
31,32,33,34,35
41,42,43,44,45
51,52,53,54,55
61,62,63,64,65
71,72,73
```

An equivalent to awk in Posix compatible shell may be:

```
diagPosix(){ diag=${1%%[!0-9+-]*} dir=$(((${2:-1}>0)?1:-1)) n=0 a=""
             while read x ; do
#                echo "testing $n $x"
                 IFS=',' eval 'set -- $x'  # Place values in pos parms.
                 a=$(( diag + n*dir    ))  # calculate position a
                 b=$(( (a<0)?0:a       ))  # low limit is zero (0)
                 d=$(( (b>$#-1)?$#-1:b ))  # upper limit is ($#-1)
#                echo "a=$a b=$b d=$d #=$# n=$n"
                 shift $d                  # remove leading parms
                 printf '%s' "$s" "$1"     # print parm (and an space)
                 s=" "                     # Next loop will have space.
                 n=$((n+1))                # In which line are we?
             done <"${3:-inputfile}"
             echo 
           }
diagPosix "$@"
```

which, with the input above, will work as follows:

```
$ ./script 0 1 inputfile
11 22 33 44 55 65 73

$ ./script -2 1 inputfile
11 21 31 42 53 64 73

$ ./script 4 -1 inputfile
15 24 33 42 51 61 71
```

The code was tested in some shells and works well.

```
ash             : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
/usr/bin/yash   : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
y2sh            : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
dash            : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
zsh/sh          : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
b203sh          : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
b204sh          : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
b205sh          : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
b30sh           : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
b32sh           : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
b41sh           : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
b42sh           : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
b43sh           : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
b44sh           : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
lksh            : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
mksh            : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
ksh93           : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
attsh           : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
zsh/ksh         : 11 22 33 44 55 65 73
```

It does fail for zsh (not in emulation) both because zsh doesn't split by default and because array numbering start on 1 (not 0).
It was tested in csh and tcsh but it doesn't work.
And it is **not** expected to work there (do not use csh for scripts!).

Solutions that work from the bottom up should be easy to build using tac on the input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative using awk:

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s%s",$NR,NR==NF?ORS:OFS}' file 
1 7 3 9 5
```

Answer (score 1):

A shell/cut-based solution:

```
index=1
while read line
do
  cut -d, -f ${index} <<< "$line"
  index=$((++index))
done < input
```